# Would magnetic reversals on Ganymede affect radiation levels at the surface?

Tags: jupiter, natural-satellites, magnetic-field, radiation

Currently the intrinsic magnetic field of Ganymede is anti-aligned with respect to the Jovian magnetic field. If this situation changed to become aligned, either due to [magnetic reversals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_reversal) of the Ganymedean dynamo or due to the reversal of Jupiter's magnetic field (which has been [predicted to undergo solar-like reversals on timescales of the order of centuries](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0019103586901776)), would there be any changes to the radiation levels at the surface?